# Ternary operator not working with reference variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, reference, ternary-operator

Why isn't this working?

```
$a = 'FOO';

$foo = $a ? &$a : 'whatever'; // <- error here

echo $foo;
```

I get a parse error :|

Comment: This isn't how you use references. You'll need to post more code to give us some context.

Comment: `Parse error: parse error in script.php line ...`

Comment: @minitech even if I replace that with a variable it's the same...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to assign a reference using a ternary statement, then you need this clumsy workaround:

```
 list($foo) = $a ? array(&$a) : array('whatever');
```

However, as said in the other answers, this seldomly saves memory.

Comment: Nope, don't works - breaks intended code semantics - try `$x=1;$y=3;list($a) = 1>0 ? [&$x] : [&$y];$a=33;var_dump($a,$x,$y);` this solution just copies reference into $foo value, but not changes memory place where $foo points to as was planned.

Answer (score 6):

Although you tagged your question [if-statement](/questions/tagged/if-statement), that's not an if statement, it's a ternary conditional expression. I've retagged it accordingly.

Now, the reason why it doesn't work is because assigning by reference is different from assigning normal value expressions in PHP. You can't use references with the `?:` operator in the same way you can't do `return &$foo;` in a function. See these manual pages about PHP references for more:

- [What References Do](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)
- [Returning References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

If you use an actual if statement, it'll work:

```
if ($a)
    $foo = &$a;
else
    $foo = 'whatever';
```

But why you'd want to use references like this is beyond me (unless this is PHP 4, and even then you shouldn't be using PHP 4 anymore).

Comment: well the variable I'm referencing too is a big object (a global variable from wordpress) and I want to create a sort of "alias" for it

Comment: An if-else statement should do it then :)

Comment: @Alex Objects in PHP are implicitly passed by reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a ? $foo = &$a : $foo = 'whatever';
```