# Assigning variables by reference and ternary operator?

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference, ternary-operator

Why ternary operator doesn't work with assignment by reference?

```
$obj     = new stdClass(); // Object to add
$result  = true; // Op result
$success = array(); // Destination array for success
$errors  = array(); // Destination array for errors

// Working
$target = &$success;
if(!$result) $target = &errors;
array_push($target, $obj);

// Not working
$target = $result ? &$success : &$errors;
array_push($target, $obj);
```

Comment: I think [this comment][1] answers it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389928/can-you-pass-by-reference-while-using-the-ternary-operator#comment-7005254

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go

```
$target = ($result ? &$success : &$errors);
```

Also your example has two typos

---

#### edit

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> Note: Please note that the ternary operator is an expression, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of an expression. This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference. The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is issued in later PHP versions.

idk if this worked before, but it doesn't anymore. if you don't wanna use an if statement, then try this:

```
$result ? $target = &$success : $target = &$errors;
```

or on separated lines ...

```
$result 
  ? $target = &$success 
  : $target = &$errors;
```

Comment: Can you explain better your answer? I'm talking about why i'm forced to use brackets and about typos. Thanks for your time dude.

Comment: Because its assigning $result to $target before executing the condition which causes an error. So to fix this, you set it to assign the result of the condition by enclosing it in parentheses.

Comment: @iim.hlk: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5931833/162228) for a work-around. The above syntax was likely only supported in older versions of PHP.

Comment: @jmikola oh!, nice 2 know P: