# Why reference can't be chosen with ternary operator?

Tags: php, reference, ternary-operator

This snippet of code:

```
$a = $condition ? &$x : &$y;
```

Generates error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in php shell code

Why PHP don't lets to choose a reference by condition in ternary operator ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551905/assigning-variables-by-reference-and-ternary-operator) help?

Comment: My guess is it's just an omission (deliberate or accidental) with the syntax parser, but I don't have any further information on this. I do see it having a reasonable expected outcome (although the code itself is really messy and probably should not be used even if allowed)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Not much. No suitable alternative, solutions like `$x=1;$y=3;list($a) = 1>0 ? [&$x] : [&$y];$a=33;var_dump($a,$x,$y);` breaks intended semantics. Also no good explanation either ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$a = &${($condition)?'x':'y'};
```

Comment: Thanks, not clean solution, but at least works.